# Flexbox ignored on mobile

Tags: css, less, flexbox

I used flexbox to spread the list items in the footer navigation across the width of footer.

It is being **displayed correctly in my browser** and also in Chrome's mobile emulation. However it is **ignored on any mobile device** I've tested with (iPhone, iPad, Samsung tablet).

Does anyone see anything obvious wrong with the code I'm not aware of? 
Below is the CSS/LESS snippet I'm using.

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;

   li {
      padding: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide link ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot on this project... :-(
I'm aware that this makes it so much more difficult to figure why it's not working. Just thought I post it here anyway... perhaps it's something obvious I don't know.

Comment: How does it display? Screenshot?

Comment: browser compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening as `display:flex` & `justify-content: space-between` are not compatible in all type of browsers.So we should have a cross-browser compatible CSS like this:

```
ul {

  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
  justify-content: space-between; 

   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;

   li {
      padding: 0;
   }
}
```

**Browser Support for** `display:flex`

- IE 11
- Edge
- FireFox 22+
- Chrome 29+
- Safari 9+
- Opera 17+
- Android Browser 4.4+

**Browser Support for** `justify-content: space-between`

- IE 11
- Edge
- FireFox 20+
- Chrome 52+
- Safari 9+
- Opera 12.1+
- Android Browser 5.6+

**Useful Links:**

https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_justify-content_flex_context

https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: Any reference or external links about this incompatibility? Is this a bug/will be fixed?

Comment: Sure I will add those links in the answer